# Question about Feynman diagrams

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, antimatter

In the picture there are feynman diagrams for two reactions. My question is: Why aren't 6.3 and 6.4 possible for the first reaction? And as a sidenote, I don't really have a good source for the rules, my professor only did a incomplete lecture about the subject. Is there a good source to read more about feynman diagrams?

[image]

Comment: try second  page http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html

Answer (score 1):

In (6.1) and (6.2) the incoming and outgoing arrows represent different particles. They probably shouldn't be drawn identically. The incoming are electrons (positrons) and outgoing are muons (anti-muons). Therefore, the process in (6.3) and (6.4) where the incoming electron/positron scatters off the potential is impossible. You must have pair annihilation into a virtual photon in order for the muon-anti-muon pair to create.

For the electron anti-electron pair scattering, you have two options - either each one scatters into itself, after interaction with the potential (6.3, 6.4), or a pair annihilation and re-creation (6.1, 6.2)